# How to determine a path When downloading file With python ftp

Tags: python, ftplib

How to determine a path When downloading file With python ftp

When downloading file From ftp Server

default Download In the path Which Work on it

How Set a path specific

Library used ftplib

```
from ftplib import FTP

 FTP = FTP('-----------')
 FTP.login(user='----------', passwd ='--------')

filename = 'index.txt'
localfile = open(filename, 'wb')
FTP.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, localfile.write, 1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
import os
path = "C:\\Users\MyHome\Documents"    
os.chdir(path)
```